# the dynamic background in android application

Tags: android, animation, android-layout

I want to program an application which is show an interface.The interface is a collection of `view` (like common interface,it compose some of `button,textview`..),but it maybe simple.
On the `interface`,i want to set an `dynamic background`.The `dynamic background` composes some of object that can be drew and changed the positions.**(example the sight of autumn leaves fall down)**.
Now,i use a thread to draw image of `object` of the `dynamic background`,but i can't put the background **below** the interface .(i don't know is the word "below" exactly but i mean that the interface is over the background.
That is all my application. 
**please help me soon,thanks alot :)**